# Find all elements with specific text selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I am trying to connect with elements that carry the contact numbers on each site. I was able to create the routine to get the numbers, extract the contact number with available formats and **regex** and the following code snippet to get the element

```
    contact_elem = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '" + phone_num + "')]")
```

Considering the example of https://www.cssfirm.com/, the contact number appears in 2 locations, the **top header** and the **bottom footer**

The element texts accompanying the contact number are as follows :

```
    <h3>CALL US TODAY AT (855) 910-7824</h3> - Footer
    <a href="tel:8559107824"> <span>Call Us<br>Today</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;(855) 910-7824</a> - Header
```

The extracted phone number matches perfectly while printing it out. For some reason, the element from the **header** part is not being detected.

I tried by searching for **elements** and even by **deleting** the **footer element** from the browser before executing the rest of the code.

What could be the reason for it to go undetected?

**P.S:** Below is the amateurish,uncorrected code. Efficiency edits/suggestions are welcome. The same code has been tested with various sites and works fine.

```
url = 'http://www.cssfirm.com/'
browser.get(url)

parsed = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('html').get_attribute('innerHTML')
s = BeautifulSoup(parsed, 'html.parser')
s = s.decode('utf-8')
phoneNumberRegex = '(\s*(?:\+?(\d{1,4}))?[-. (]*(\d{1,})[-. )]*(\d{3}|[A-Z0-9]+)[-. \/]*(\d{4}|[A-Z0-9]+)[-. \/]?(\d{4}|[A-Z0-9]+)?(?: *x(\d+))?\s*)'
custom_re = ['([0-9]{4,4} )([0-9]{3,3} )([0-9]{4,4})',
             '([0-9]{3,3} )([0-9]{4,4} )([0-9]{4,4})',
             '(\+[0-9]{2,2}-)([0-9]{4,4}-)([0-9]{4,4}-)(0)',
             '(\([0-9]{3,3}\) )([0-9]{3,3}-)([0-9]{4,4})',
             '(\+[0-9]{2,2} )(\(0\)[0-9]{4,4} )([0-9]{4,6})',
             '([0-9]{5,5} )([0-9]{6,6})',
             '(\+[0-9]{2,2}\(0\))([0-9]{4,4} )([0-9]{4,4})',
             '(\+[0-9]{2,2} )([0-9]{3,3} )([0-9]{4,4} )([0-9]{3,3})',
             '([0-9]{3,3}-)([0-9]{3,3}-)([0-9]{4,4})']

phones = []
phones = re.findall(phoneNumberRegex, s)
phone_num_list = ()
phone_num = ''
matched = 0

for phoneHeader in phones:
    #phoneHeader = phoneHeader.decode('utf-8')
    for ph_cnd in phoneHeader:
        for pttrn in custom_re:
            phones = re.findall(pttrn,ph_cnd)
            if(phones):
                phone_num_list = phones
                for x in phone_num_list:
                    phone_num = ''.join(x)
                try:
                    contact_elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '" + phone_num + "')]")
                    phone_num_txt = contact_elem.text
                    if(phone_num_txt):
                        matched = 1
                        break
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    pass
                if(matched == 1):
                    break
        if(matched == 1):
            break
    if(matched == 1):
        break

print("Phone number :",phone_num) <-- Perfect output
contact_elem <--empty for header or just the footer element
```

**EDIT**

Code updated. Forgot an important piece. Moreover, there is sleep time given in between to give time for the page to load. Considering it trivial, I haven't included them for a quick read.

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: contact_elem should be a list of both the instances of the element from the webpage. Please see the edit. @QHarr

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary solution by searching for the partial link text, as the number also comes on the link.

```
    contact_elem2 = browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text(phone_num)
```

However, this does not answer the generic question as to why that text was ignored within the element.